# Async test in jest tutorial

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Hi I am trying same as this example tutorial but it is giving me error.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

```
  expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "Paul"
    Received:
      undefined

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.

      14 | it('works with async/await and resolves', async () => {
      15 |   expect.assertions(1);
    > 16 |   await expect(user.getUserName(5)).resolves.toEqual('Paul');
         |                                                ^
      17 | });
```

everyting is same my server returns a json but jest says undefined after http get

```
{"id":10002,"name":"test","passportNumber":"A1234568"}
```

Comment: I would spy on `getUserName` and return a mocked Promise. Tests shouldn't do HTTP requests, these should be mocked.

Comment: same as tutorial

Comment: tutorial code is not working

Answer (score 0):

it returns undefined because source function was not a promise function. it was plain function.